# How to get NSDate with nil value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm a beginner in Swift and coding in general. Right now I'm trying to develop the piece of the code to set up the time limit for the action only once a day.

```
@IBAction func yesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    //To retrive the control date value. First time it has nil value
    var controlDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("controlDate") as? NSDate
    //To check current date to compare with
    var currentDate = NSDate()
    // To check if time interval between controlDate and currentDate is less than 1 day
    var timeInterval = controlDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow
    var dayInSeconds = 24 * 3600
    if timeInterval < dayInSeconds {

        //show alert with message "You've done it recently. Pls wait a bit"

    } else {

        //perfome the action
        //update the value of NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("controlDate") with current time stamp 
    }
}
```

Instead of checking if the controlTime var has nil value to catch the App first time running I was trying to develop some shorter, universal code for both case, first time and the rest times when the controlDate var will be saved in UserDefaults.

Nevertheless it doesn't work properly (( I'd appreciate your help a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dayInSeconds` is the wrong type to make the comparison.  Type inference is determining that it should be an `Int` while `timeIntervalSinceNow` is a Double under the covers.  And thus, you can't definitively compare an Int and a Double with accuracy.

Create `dayInSeconds` in this way so that it's type is inferred as a Double, rather than an Int.

```
var controlDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("controlDate") as? NSDate
var currentDate = NSDate()
var timeInterval = controlDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow
//*** HERES THE CHANGE***
var dayInSeconds = 24.0 * 3600
if timeInterval < dayInSeconds {
}
```

Since you aren't attempting to call a method on `timeInterval` optional unwrapping is not necessary in this case.

Comment: `timeInterval < dayInSeconds` evaluates to `true` if `timeInterval` is `nil`, so the first case "You've done it recently" would be executed on the first run of the app. **However**, it seems to me that the test should actually be `if timeInterval > -dayInSeconds`, and then the `nil` case also works as expected.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, but somehow I skipped you comment (( Well you are absolutely right pointing `timeInterval` with `nil` value case. However I guess your idea won't work properly as well because in that case `if timeInterval > -dayInSeconds` always be true. Moreover I think the idea to make the code shorter is not good at all. Because it will make the code difficult to read. So I'm going to catch nil case separately. Thx for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

`timeInterval` is an Optional, you need to unwrap it first

```
if let ti = timeInterval {
    if ti < dayInSeconds {
        ...
    }
}
```

[More on Optionals](https://www.google.com.uy/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQygQwAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fswift%2Fconceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FTheBasics.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014097-CH5-XID_496&ei=zpt0VLK2MMbQggSPyoH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNFCMPaZMzfhAnYQXzDE0iDt-1Lq5A)