# I cannot make NSUserdefaults work for me as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm developing the application that allows users to vote once a day. To set up that time limit I declare votingStatus Boolean variable. Its value depends on controlDate that can be "nil" if first time running the app and then votingStatus is true.

However the application doesn't work properly. The votingStatus variable changes its value only after reset the application. That is obviously not what I expected. I need the check and update votingStatus variable each time a user clicks the button.

Thank you in advance for sharing your minds how to correct the application flow!

Below the code I wrote inside class ViewController: UIViewController { }

```
var votingStatus: Bool?

@IBAction func yesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Check if votingStatus is true
    if votingStatus == true {
        //I'm using Parse for backend
        var score = PFObject(className: "score")
        score.setObject(1, forKey: "vote")
        score.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (succes: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if succes == true {
                println("Done with ID \(score.objectId)")
                //update NSUserdefaults
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "controlDate")
                // should I NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() below?
            } else {
                println(error)
                //show alert
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Status is \(votingStatus)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Find if user haven't already voted within 1 day so if his/her voting status true
    // var votingStatus: Bool?

    //To retrive the control date value. First time it has nil value
    var controlDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("controlDate") as? NSDate
    var timeInterval = controlDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow
    var dayInSeconds = 24.0 * 3600

    if controlDate == nil {
        votingStatus = true
    } else {
        if timeInterval < dayInSeconds {
            votingStatus = false
        } else {
            votingStatus = true
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Yes...you should call `synchronize()` (if that's your question)

Comment: it won't work though properly ((

Comment: Have a think about what value `tomeIntervalSinceNow` will return for a date in the past?  How many seconds is 1 minute ago from now? In other words, what number do I need to add to "now" to get the time a minute ago. Then look at your comparison. Also `viewDidLoad` is probably not the best place for this code - it will only get executed once. What if the "day" expires while this view is visible?

Comment: Did you read my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130001/how-to-get-nsdate-with-nil-value#comment42760584_27130266 to an answer to your previous question?

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right. Thank you! I'm going to fix `timeInterval` adding minus. Is it correct? As for the place where to add the `controlDate` var check piece of code I have no idea so far. May be inside `func yesButtonPressed`. But I don't like it. Because it's not only button of the view and all other buttons should also check votingStatus. Could you please make your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewDidLoad() is called once until your view is removed from memory so if system keeps your application in memory for a week viewDidLoad() will not be called. You can either set up a day timer in addition to viewDidLoad() or you can check controlDate value as you do in viewDidLoad() in yesButtonPressed func.

Comment: This is *a* problem but not the main problem.  The main problem is that the time interval will be negative as it is in the past, making the < comparison incorrect

Comment: @Андрій Жицький Thank you for the reply! Correct! But what do you mean by "set up a day timer in addition to viewDidLoad()"? P.S. God bless Ukraine!

Comment: @Paulw11 I made the correction by adding minus to dayInSeconds.

Comment: @Maga Glory to the heroes:) sorry for a late answer. The problem with viewDidLoad is that it may be called on one day and yesButtonPressed two days later. So even in viewDidLoad required time interval has not passed in yesButtonPressed you need to vote. This might be a rare case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, just a quick answer: Maybe your method call "timeIntervalSinceNow" on an Optional is the problem. Why don't you put that line into the if-block, where you can be sure that there is a value and wrap it with ! Instead of ?

```
    var dayInSeconds = 24.0 * 3600

    if controlDate == nil {
        votingStatus = true
    } else {

        **var timeInterval = controlDate!.timeIntervalSinceNow**

        if timeInterval < dayInSeconds {
            votingStatus = false
        } else {
            votingStatus = true
        }
    }
}
```